# I am unable to understand if(std::cin>>) loops

Tags: c++

I am completely new to Programming in general and currently self-learning C++. Its my first day learning and I am currently understanding loops.

Here is the code I am trying to work with and understand.

```
int start = 0, end = 0;
  
  while(true){
      
      std::cout<<"Input a starting number: ";
      if(std::cin>>start){
          //PLACEHOLDER TEXT
      }else{
          std::cout<<"You have entered an incorrect starting number. Please enter again.";
          std::cout<<std::endl;
          start = 0;
      }
  }
```

So, what happens is that once I give an incorrect input, like an alphabet. It prints the else case message and starts the while loop again but it doesnt give me the prompt to input again. It just starts as if the case is already false and continues the loop using else case.

I've tried setting start = 0 in else case so it is an integer instead of a garbage number but no luck.

Why this is happening and any way to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin` is in the fail state after the attempt to read a letter to int and a letter is kept in the input stream. You should clear the std::cin state and ignore the previous input before the if or in the else:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore();
```

---

Usually you should always ignore input before reading std::cin after an input request. It protects from reading of random chars input by an impatient user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining why and how to fix it! My background is not computer science but I hope I can become good at C++ one day

Comment: I'm not sure that this is good advice. It introduces races and other problems when standard input is redirected, e.g. from a file. Unfortunately, C++'s library is insufficient to handle this correctly. You have to use platform-specific means of detecting whether the input comes from an interactive tty, and only do the ignoring then...